# Tabulator - conditional formatting of individual cells

Tags: tabulator

I have an html table that i have converted into a tabulator element. it looks amazing. one small issue - i have php code in the table that changes the color of certain cells based on their contents. so if for example, in the column "type", if a cell's value is "INBOUND", it made the cell green. "OUTBOUND" made it red etc....

but now that it's a tabulator element, all the styling is overridden by the tabulator script. So as far as i can see, my options to fix this are :

1. somehow tell tabulator to respect my formatting choices for that column so that my inline css works
2. do the conditional formatting inside tabulator (but i can't find any answers on how)
3. some other method you guys know of that i haven't found

for what it's worth, this is what i had in the html (which is being overreidden)

```
    <tr <?php if ($row_transactions['transactionType']=="OUTBOUND") {
                  echo " style=\"background-color:#C00; color:#FFF;\""; }       
         elseif ($row_transactions['transactionType']=="INBOUND"){
                  echo " style=\"background-color:#070 ; color:#FFF;\"";} 
         else {echo " style=\"background-color:#C90; color:#FFF;\"";}?>>
```

for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tabulator will ignore any styling of the data inside the table. But the good news is you can use [Custom Formatters](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/format#format-custom) to format the cell in any way you like

Comment: Ok, i found out why it wasn't working.... I needed to omit the "name" parameter in column definition, and keep only "title" so it wouldnt override my auto generated columns. But then the color change didn't work.   it was because there was some outdated mentions of what function to use to change the color. documentation said use 

cell.getElement().css({"background-colo"r:"#f00"});

but what needed to be used was :

 cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#A6A6DF"

now it works fine.

Comment: Where did you see the outdated code examples? I will get those fixed straight away

Comment: it was my own fault. i did a google search and the incorrect method came up as one of the first results. I clicked on the link and little did i know, it was to your old documentation on github and your site. but because i wasnt reading from the top of the document, i missed the notice that it was old documentation. i figured it out after finding a mention of a related issue on another stack overflow question

Comment: ahh, i will take down the old github documentation it is years out of date at this point

Comment: by the way oli, regarding documentation, I can't find anywhere in your docs a full list of the methods and properties available for cells, rows, etc. for example, if i have the following :

row.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#A6A6DF";

are all options after .style essentially standard css syntax? 

so essentially i am asking : 

 getElement().(what options are there for here, and whats the syntax)?

Comment: the getElement function returns a standard JS DOM node, it is not a tabulator convention, you can call any of the standard JS DOM Node functions on it, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp